# Problems with sessions in Spring (SessionAttributes)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I have a problem with a spring sessions, my controller have this code:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("placeForm")
```

The problem is that:

1. Open the first url that contains a form.
2. Open the same url in other window.
3. Send the form open in step 1.

The data that contain the object placeForm is the last object (step 2), not step 1...

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Does the `placeForm` object not contain values?

Comment: Define "*Open the same url in other window.*". If that is a tab or window opened with CTRL+N that isn't a new browser. All session data is shared between the windows/tabs. There eis a single session not multiple, that  basically comes down how browsers work and has nothing to do with your application.